# Asp.net - Stack Empty

Tags: asp.net, panel

In my asp.net webform project I'm trying to add asp:panel for search field. I need to use defaultbutton attribute.

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" runat="server" onkeypress="searchclick('btnSearch',event);" id="txtSearch" />

        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnSearch" itemid="btnSeach" onserverclick="btnSearch_ServerClick" runat="server" type="submit"><i
class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

When I try to do this I took error like.
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdLcS.png)

If I just remove **defaultbutton** attribute the error is gone.

Comment: can you post code behind code?

Comment: It is empty yet. @jjj

Comment: please include image to question, not link to it